# Disable automatically-generated comments in classes (backend editor)

Tags: abap, sap-gui

Currently, I am "forced" to develop my reports with SE80 / SE24, etc. and I can't use eclipse. There I've seen that if you have the "Source Code-Based" view in Z-Classes, above every method the signature is shown as a comment. See in the following picture:

[image: Example Comment Picture]

Well, I know that those comments are not really in the source code, but shown anyway (generated somehow).

**Do you know a way how to disable those "comments"?**

I find them unnecessary and I am losing the overview over the class. And instead of a 27-row implementation part of a class I've got an 88-row-long implementation part.

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These signature comments are automatically generated by the SAP GUI based class editor reached through transactions SE24 and SE80.

Use the ABAP Development Tools to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to disable those comments. I genereally prefer the form editor when forced to use SE80, I think it gives a better overview. The best would be if you were allowed to use Eclipse, but politics can be difficult to change.

Comment: Hmmm.. okay, thanks - I thought there might be any chance to disable this.

Comment: "I genereally prefer the form editor [...]" Be careful with personal preferences. :-) Mixing different editors in the same team can cause undesired conflicts. For example, the form-based editor reorders all methods in alphabetical order whenever you edit a class, overwriting any manual orders your co-developers might have introduced in their source-code based editors. It's a good idea to have the team agree on one editor, and stick to it.

Comment: @Florian Are you sure about that? Afaik the form-based editor does keep everything as is until you click the sort button, which usually sorts based on visibility and then name.